# 36Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource '<URL>' with computed SHA-256 integrity ''. The resource has been blocked

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web-deployment, blazor-webassembly

[Getting this error on server deploy blazor webassembly. But Client working fine  app on local IIS server
Any help ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alHKD.png)

Comment: Try to update packages and deploy again, or try to set `<BlazorCacheBootResources>false</BlazorCacheBootResources>`  to false

Comment: i have added this but could not get any success

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue here. Started after my 1st packages upgrades since switching to VS2022 and .NET6 for my blazor app (Azure deployed).

I was even able to get rid of it when downgrading to previous package version. This confirms an old reference is still alive somewhere, not updated.

Solution steps :

1. close VS2022
2. Delete bin and obj folders from both Client and Server (note: tried client only and, it did not work but, did not try server only).
3. open solution in VS2022
4. Publish

The solution on this other Stack-overflow article worked for me:
[Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource in Blazor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926878/failed-to-find-a-valid-digest-in-the-integrity-attribute-for-resource-in-blazo)